# finding Excel Error Cells in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I know there is a way to get the Error cells in VBA as below

```
Set rng = xlBook1.Sheets(s1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
```

can any one provide me the way to do this in C#.

basically to get all the cells that is having errors in the formula like (#DIV/0!, #REF!) in a range

Answer (score 2):

I got it...

rngTemp = (Excel.Range)wsCTAWK13.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeFormulas, Excel.XlSpecialCellsValue.xlErrors);